# how to format my array structures

Tags: php

I have this array structure.

```
array(
       [1]=> Parent
       [2]=> Child
       [3]=> Child Child      
 )
```

How to create this structure below in php :

```
array(
       "Parent",
       "Child",
       "Child Child" 
     )
```

Comment: what is the difference between them? Fro where you got the first one?

Comment: `$newArray = array_values($oldArray);` will reset the indexing to 0,1,2 rather than 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function to extract the values of an array.

Demo:

```
php > var_export(array_values([1=>'Parent', 2=>'Child', 3=>'Child child']));
array (
  0 => 'Parent',
  1 => 'Child',
  2 => 'Child child',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to print the array differently :

```
<?php
    $alpha=array(1,2,3,4);
    print_r($alpha);

    echo "<br />";
    foreach($alpha as $a){
        echo "$a <br />";
    }
?>
```

Output :

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 ) 
1 
2 
3 
4
```